# Why does Ubuntu keep logging me out?

Tags: logout

I'm not sure what's going on, but Ubuntu keeps logging me out, each time I play long videos.
Not just when i play them, but specifically, when I jump around the video 2-4 times, or when i move the window around...

This happened to me before on this computer, so at one point i replaced the OS with windows, and the problem disappeared... Now I decided to try Ubuntu again, and the problem persists..

Basically, what happens is that the video screen goes black, then the whole monitor goes black, and i find myself at the login screen, with my account logged out..

I'd like to know what's wrong, and any possible ways to stop this constant irritation...

Comment: Try launching your video application from the console to see if anr error messages appear. Also try another video application like VLC

Comment: I'll try from the console, but i've tried using other video applications.. VLC is the last one i tried, with the same problem..

Comment: Yeah, it just did the same thing again...

Comment: Sorry for digging this out but I am experiencing the same problem right now on Ubuntu 20.04LTS wih DDE. I have a laptop with external 2nd monitor attached to it and USBC dock with 3rd screen. I get the logout problem when I move the windows between screens, when i try to stick them to the screen edge (to fill certain part of screen) and other similar stuff like these actions. This does NOT happen all the time. I have days when i work on that laptop for days without issues, and they are days when it happens like each time a move a window. Also it feels like it happens when i move the windows es

Answer (score 3):

you might be crashing your X server.  Next time it happens log back in and have a peek at the bottom of the file /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old and see what it has to say.

Comment: What exactly am I looking for? I tried it twice, making a copy of the file each time... There's a difference in the numbers, so yeah, it was changed, but i'm not sure what i'm looking for here...
`[   433.123] Segmentation fault at address 0x1b8
[   433.123] 
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   433.123] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
  at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   433.123] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.`

That part might have something to do with it, though i'm not sure..

Comment: ah, ok.  "Segmentation fault" is what happens when a program tries to access some memory that doesn't belong to it.  In this case, it's your Xorg process that's behaving badly.  It's ok if the numbers in brackets change, but it the segmentation fault address the same each time?  Have you tried going to http://wiki.x.org for help, like the error message suggests?

Comment: If you mean the "Segmentation fault at address 0x1b8" part, then yes, the address stays the same each time... and I'm not really sure how to ask for help on that site, other than to possibly e-mail them... I don't really know how to use IRC very well xD

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try looking at your Brightness & Lock Settings, It could be the nonactive timeout might be kicking in.  If you don't move the mouse or touch the keyboard in that time, it will go dark and send you to the login screen like you described.  Maybe turn the lock off or increasing the time will solve your problem.

Comment: OP specifically said it happens when they jump around in the file or move the video player window around.  That implies to me that they're not reaching a login screen due to inactivity.