# Lubuntu 20.04 LTS logging out unexpectedly

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, crash, logout

In short, after some update, my Lubuntu started logging me out several times a day all of sudden. I see no pattern to it, a black screen appears and after a few seconds I'm on a login desktop.

I see that this problem is quite common in Ubuntu, unfortunately with a low fix-rate:

[Ubuntu 18.04 logs out unexpectedly or crashes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056571/ubuntu-18-04-logs-out-unexpectedly-or-crashes)

[Automatically Being Logged Out Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832404/automatically-being-logged-out-lubuntu)

[Ubuntu randomly, suddenly logs out my user session back to login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127488/ubuntu-randomly-suddenly-logs-out-my-user-session-back-to-login)

[Random and sudden logging out from my user session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617910/random-and-sudden-logging-out-from-my-user-session)

[Why does Ubuntu keep logging me out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175539/why-does-ubuntu-keep-logging-me-out)

https://superuser.com/questions/27780/random-unwanted-log-off-in-ubuntu

---

Related bugs:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1455916

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/760695

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/980519

---

#### EDIT

I'm now sure, that the logging off is caused by [DisplayLink](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) drivers, as it only happens when I'm using the docking stations with another monitor.

---

#### My attempts:

So far I'm not sure, what to do now - I'm skeptical about changing my mouse cursor, monitor brightness, and similar advice, which is very specific and probably not the cause here. Also, my PC is overheating.

#### Logs:

**/var/log/syslog** (~ 1 min before log out)

```
Jun 22 14:10:01 martin-pc whoopsie[2512]: [14:10:01] Reported OOPS ID 4bd97b92-b481-11ea-af96-fa163e983629
Jun 22 14:10:02 martin-pc kernel: [42667.109916] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827802.980:179): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/19c1fdaca161d2599153746a76141c1a.png" pid=26411 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:03 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: The client's potential public address list is now set to 158.196.114.188, 2001:718:1001:1C1:CC6:B16E:648B:4ABC
Jun 22 14:10:04 martin-pc kernel: [42668.392742] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827804.264:180): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/19b23220b16e2861f6ad643d6c30c1b8.png" pid=26464 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:04 martin-pc kernel: [42669.064521] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827804.936:181): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/7b9de9383e187fb76c9c5bb3b982e7d3.png" pid=26539 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:05 martin-pc kernel: [42669.303603] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827805.172:182): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/658e01d9f61a53a9833079531679f20e.png" pid=26587 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:05 martin-pc kernel: [42669.464472] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827805.336:183): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/19a51d7e2d15b6a398f9cac40a3c35a2.png" pid=26608 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:05 martin-pc kernel: [42669.607032] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827805.476:184): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/307bd64fdc9763e20b0e1d24cba9accc.png" pid=26623 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:05 martin-pc kernel: [42669.706970] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827805.576:185): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/4213125f25e1aaef6e423c45e92fbb8f.png" pid=26635 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:05 martin-pc kernel: [42669.844723] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827805.716:186): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/2d66fd138d5f10f0b1cbb094c1d293d7.png" pid=26647 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:06 martin-pc kernel: [42671.004324] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827806.876:187): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/7a910c5ddd46849d1740242f87147f72.png" pid=26658 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc kernel: [42671.277916] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827807.148:188): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/743fd574787147a718f7b1db86a8438b.png" pid=26786 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 119...
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: dbus.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopped target Paths.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: ubuntu-report.path: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd-resolved[975]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Stopped target Timers.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: dbus.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: dirmngr.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: gpg-agent-browser.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: gpg-agent-extra.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: gpg-agent-ssh.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: gpg-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: pk-debconf-helper.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed Sound System.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: snapd.session-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Finished Exit the Session.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[23726]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd-resolved[975]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: user@119.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 119.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/119...
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[2045]: run-user-119.mount: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: run-user-119.mount: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@119.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/119.
Jun 22 14:10:07 martin-pc systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 119.
Jun 22 14:10:08 martin-pc kernel: [42672.190096] kauditd_printk_skb: 2 callbacks suppressed
Jun 22 14:10:08 martin-pc kernel: [42672.190098] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827808.060:191): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/7ae5ba26cc2d12e49018b67ec8f5ebb0.png" pid=26874 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:09 martin-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:10 martin-pc kernel: [42674.241009] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827810.112:192): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/62b19bb1a34357eac27be423d69c49cb.png" pid=26906 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:10 martin-pc dbus-daemon[2097]: [session uid=1000 pid=2097] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets' requested by ':1.311' (uid=1000 pid=25308 comm="./jetbrains-toolbox --minimize " label="unconfined")
Jun 22 14:10:10 martin-pc dbus-daemon[2097]: [session uid=1000 pid=2097] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.secrets'
Jun 22 14:10:10 martin-pc kernel: [42674.368825] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827810.240:193): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/24f2a81a3cdc937358e3df83119a19db.png" pid=27086 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:10 martin-pc kernel: [42674.717627] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827810.588:194): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/297a00a0997cc1da1c2a5abe3675f21f.png" pid=27104 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:11 martin-pc kernel: [42675.282034] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827811.152:195): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/51d16eb9926f63f70dada2cbd2ff2d37.png" pid=27134 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:11 martin-pc kernel: [42675.476818] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827811.348:196): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/bc99caf053903b85e0eea32b1eb7cd23.png" pid=27185 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:11 martin-pc kernel: [42675.591566] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827811.460:197): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/5632ebcd5431fd0a4b2be441f59b2954.png" pid=27210 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:11 martin-pc kernel: [42675.757501] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827811.628:198): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/4a5286479adb81cc34f733a8af6f71fd.png" pid=27222 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:12 martin-pc kernel: [42676.239938] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827812.112:199): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/f915953db39a74f6c90370e87df6f7c4.png" pid=27239 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:12 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: OnTransportInitiateComplete File: ../../vpn/Common/IP/TlsTransport.cpp Line: 418 Invoked Function: ISocketTransportCB::OnTransportInitiateComplete Return Code: -31588316 (0xFE1E0024) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 
Jun 22 14:10:12 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: OnOpenRequestComplete File: ../../vpn/Common/IP/HttpProbeAsync.cpp Line: 302 Invoked Function: CHttpSessionAsync::OnOpenRequestComplete Return Code: -31588316 (0xFE1E0024) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 
Jun 22 14:10:12 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: OnTimerExpired File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/SocketTransport.cpp Line: 1815 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::postConnectProcessing Return Code: -31588316 (0xFE1E0024) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 
Jun 22 14:10:12 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1538 Invoked Function: CHttpProbeAsync::SendProbe Return Code: -27000818 (0xFE64000E) Description: HTTP_PROBE_ASYNC_ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT HTTPS (host: 195.113.113.10)
Jun 22 14:10:12 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: TestAccessToSG File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1380 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::analyzeHttpResponse Return Code: -28901363 (0xFE47000D) Description: NETENVIRONMENT_ERROR_PROBE_INCOMPLETE:Network Probe could not contact target 
Jun 22 14:10:12 martin-pc kernel: [42676.642444] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827812.512:200): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/a6460631cc66ccf85d716de296e8b7ce.png" pid=27276 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:13 martin-pc kernel: [42677.372571] kauditd_printk_skb: 3 callbacks suppressed
Jun 22 14:10:13 martin-pc kernel: [42677.372573] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827813.244:204): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/f29236c9f96799f6804477d3363c26a3.png" pid=27354 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:13 martin-pc kernel: [42677.913692] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827813.784:205): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/110481e53616de3d76734db9c955a11a.png" pid=27372 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:14 martin-pc kernel: [42678.350642] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827814.220:206): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/5a2b6182d416111d96d72d671150dc1e.png" pid=27407 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:14 martin-pc kernel: [42678.466851] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827814.336:207): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/38ec69f093e5e370616217dd140a4a00.png" pid=27435 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:14 martin-pc kernel: [42678.587163] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827814.456:208): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/89e69aa30efeb544e8bb9774478f1cfd.png" pid=27444 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:14 martin-pc kernel: [42678.807208] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827814.676:209): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/28297642783dc30cf63cbd22abe21b1b.png" pid=27454 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:15 martin-pc kernel: [42679.181090] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827815.052:210): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/056ccf21605f35632b272ddff5c6f8d7.png" pid=27474 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:15 martin-pc kernel: [42679.279929] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827815.152:211): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/14ca11a8484653bc697feee0787fbb8d.png" pid=27503 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:15 martin-pc systemd-resolved[975]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jun 22 14:10:15 martin-pc kernel: [42679.733330] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827815.604:212): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/419e350f64f7e779e6a5e612a814ba00.png" pid=27514 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:15 martin-pc kernel: [42680.055927] audit: type=1400 audit(1592827815.928:213): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/martin/.cache/thumbnails/normal/561cbc7ef5dd519dc611392012f3a370.png" pid=27557 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 22 14:10:15 martin-pc systemd-resolved[975]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: OnOpenRequestComplete File: ../../vpn/Common/IP/HttpProbeAsync.cpp Line: 302 Invoked Function: CHttpSessionAsync::OnOpenRequestComplete Return Code: -31588316 (0xFE1E0024) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: OnTimerExpired File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/SocketTransport.cpp Line: 1815 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::postConnectProcessing Return Code: -31588316 (0xFE1E0024) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1538 Invoked Function: CHttpProbeAsync::SendProbe Return Code: -27000818 (0xFE64000E) Description: HTTP_PROBE_ASYNC_ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT HTTP (host: 195.113.113.10)
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: TestAccessToSG File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1474 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::analyzeHttpResponse Return Code: -28901363 (0xFE47000D) Description: NETENVIRONMENT_ERROR_PROBE_INCOMPLETE:Network Probe could not contact target 
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 865 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::IsSGAccessible Return Code: -28901363 (0xFE47000D) Description: NETENVIRONMENT_ERROR_PROBE_INCOMPLETE:Network Probe could not contact target 
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 298 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testNetwork Return Code: -28901363 (0xFE47000D) Description: NETENVIRONMENT_ERROR_PROBE_INCOMPLETE:Network Probe could not contact target 
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 336 Incomplete probe count is 1
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 438 Network accessible. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 10 seconds.
Jun 22 14:10:20 martin-pc acvpnagent[1078]: Current network state: Network accessible
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc whoopsie-upload-all[24778]: /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc whoopsie-upload-all[24778]: Collecting info for /var/crash/_usr_bin_pcmanfm-qt.1000.crash...
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc whoopsie-upload-all[24778]: Marking /var/crash/_usr_bin_pcmanfm-qt.1000.crash for whoopsie upload
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc whoopsie-upload-all[24778]: All reports processed
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc systemd[1]: Finished Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc whoopsie[2512]: [14:10:27] Parsing /var/crash/_usr_bin_pcmanfm-qt.1000.crash.
Jun 22 14:10:27 martin-pc whoopsie[2512]: [14:10:27] Uploading /var/crash/_usr_bin_pcmanfm-qt.1000.crash.
Jun 22 14:10:29 martin-pc wpa_supplicant[1067]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED c4:14:3c:12:70:e1 0
Jun 22 14:10:29 martin-pc wpa_supplicant[1067]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED c4:14:3c:38:79:3e 0
Jun 22 14:10:29 martin-pc wpa_supplicant[1067]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED c4:14:3c:7a:38:1e 0
Jun 22 14:10:29 martin-pc wpa_supplicant[1067]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED c4:14:3c:38:79:31 0
Jun 22 14:10:29 martin-pc wpa_supplicant[1067]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED c4:14:3c:7a:38:11 0
```

**_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash** Backtrace

```
 [ 42642.734] (EE) Backtrace:
 [ 42642.735] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13c) [0x56021786bdec]
 [ 42642.737] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x60) [0x7f6df963c41f]
 [ 42642.739] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f6df947918b]
 [ 42642.742] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0x12b) [0x7f6df9458859]
 [ 42642.743] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
 [ 42642.743] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6df76783a7]
 [ 42642.745] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0x2036b7) [0x7f6df826ab97]
 [ 42642.746] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_zink+0x24f35) [0x7f6df76c8685]
 [ 42642.748] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_zink+0x24fa4) [0x7f6df76c8784]
 [ 42642.751] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
 [ 42642.751] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6df9f90c50]
 [ 42642.753] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
 [ 42642.753] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6df9f93860]
 [ 42642.753] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (BlockHandler+0xa5) [0x56021770f9a5]
 [ 42642.754] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0x122) [0x560217865462]
 [ 42642.754] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x117) [0x56021770ad07]
 [ 42642.754] (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3b4) [0x56021770efd4]
 [ 42642.756] (EE) 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f6df945a0b3]
 [ 42642.756] (EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2e) [0x5602176f8a3e]
```

There is also a crash log for PcManFM, but I suppose, that its crash is caused by XOrg.

Comment: Are you using Lubuntu's LXQt desktop?  Did you fresh install a Lubuntu LXQt release? or upgrade from a LXDE or other release?  The bugs and links you provided seem to relate to GNOME/Unity and one to LXDE which won't apply to a LXQt desktop if you clean installed a Lubuntu LXQt release (as is suggested & supported by the Lubuntu team). Why do you think they relate? and tagged them?  (esp. bug reports, as I see no connection and why you seem to think they relate)

Comment: @guiverc unrelated but please take a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/1252479/248158

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I'm using LXQt desktop and I upgraded from Lubuntu 19.10. Also, I mentioned the other questions and bug reports due to the similarity of the problem, not necessarily the cause.

Comment: ack @DKBose, I saw the other post ~two nights ago but have struggled to find time to look into keybindings & respond... have given a little..     upgrades from prior LXQt releases (eg. 19.10) shouldn't impact anything..  Are you sure the crash log is for `pcmanfm` ?? as that's not been used by Lubuntu since 18.04 (Lubuntu uses `pcmanfm-qt` now as in your posts)  `pcmanfm` is GTK2 based using a very different stack..  Overheating is a  clue maybe, but logout isn't a hang (system recovers; not Xorg) but is your machine accessed remotely? as I see network (anyconnect?) errors

Comment: @guiverc I've edited my question - the logging off is probably connected to using DisplayLink.